# In Django, form submit is working but not able to parse user input

Tags: python, django

User can able to submit the form without any issue, however user input data does not parse into database. Only predefined default data is parsing.

In my opinion, my model has an issue however I could not able to find because first time I am creating an object with ForeignKey and my knowledge on 'instance' part of the model is limited. Or I am too tired...

My models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ticketer')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='open', blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='Ticket', blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=PRIORITY_LEVEL, default='low', blank=False)
    display = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    handler = models.CharField(max_length=14, default='MT', blank=True)
    response = models.TextField(blank=True, default='We are working on your ticket!')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_or_update_ticket(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    Ticket.objects.create(user=instance)
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def add_ticket_view(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_ticket_form = AddTicketForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if add_ticket_form.is_valid():
            add_ticket_form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your ticket was successfully submitted!'))
            return redirect('..')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        add_ticket_form = AddTicketForm(instance=request.user)
        context = {
        'add_ticket_form': add_ticket_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'pages/user-ticket-add.html', {
        'add_ticket_form': add_ticket_form
    })
```

My forms.py

```
class AddTicketForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ('priority', 'subject', 'body',)
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", view=dashboard_view, name="dashboard"),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/profile/$', views.get_user_profile),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile_view),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/tickets/$', views.user_ticket_view),
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/tickets/add/$', views.add_ticket_view, name='add_ticket_view'),
]
```

My add-ticket.html:

```
                    <form method="POST" class="add-ticket-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ add_ticket_form|crispy }}
                    <div class="text-right mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn waves-effect mb-1 waves-light">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
```

Thank you all for your help guys.

UPDATE - SOLUTION:

If anyone come to this question, I was not passing the form as data, I was passing it with a related user. However this is not OneToOne relation, USER is a ForeignKey here.

my views.py now and working:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def add_ticket_view(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_ticket_form = AddTicketForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if add_ticket_form.is_valid():
            data = add_ticket_form.save(commit=False)
            data.user = request.user
            data.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Your ticket was successfully submitted!'))
            return redirect('dashboard:user_ticket', username)
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        add_ticket_form = AddTicketForm(instance=request.user)
        context = {
        'add_ticket_form': add_ticket_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'pages/user-ticket-add.html', {
        'add_ticket_form': add_ticket_form
    })
```

Comment: any logs would help..

Comment: does it work without @transaction.atomic?

Comment: @flaxon Unfortunately does not work without 'transaction.atomic' and  not giving any error log :(

Comment: start with a print to see if you pass `if add_ticket_form.is_valid():` also try to print the form

Comment: your instance passed to the `AddTicketForm` should be a `Ticket` object, can you also post your template?